# How do i configure a Logitech G502 Spectrum under Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, mouse, colors, configure

I'm thinking about buying a Logitech G502 *Spectrum* (the G502 with RGB LEDs) but as I am running Linux (Speciified in Debian @ work, ubuntu @work and archlinux @home) I am woundering how to setup colors directly under a linux environment.

As far as I know from some review videos on youtube, it uses Logitech's default Gaming Software to acheive this under windows, but sadly as far as i remember there is no official software from logitech supporting linux.

So how do i change the rgb color under linux (well each distro). I would be fine with a shell script doing it :) - But I am *NOT* willing to setup a profile ander a windows environment.

Comment: I imagine someone has to write a proprietary driver for this.  I wanted the same for my RGB Corsair keyboard, and fortunately someone did write a proprietary driver for it.  I would be willing to contribute to such a project, but I am not knowledgeable enough in Linux kernel development to initiate one.

Answer (score 54):

You can use [Piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper), which relies on libratbag.

[Installing it is simple](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/wiki/Installation):

- Fedora: `dnf install piper`
- Arch: `pacman -S piper`
- Ubuntu: add this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libratbag-piper/+archive/ubuntu/piper-libratbag-git), and then install using `sudo apt install piper`
- OpenSUSE: `zypper install piper`

Then you just configure your mouse via the gui!

I have a g502s myself, and as far as I can see everything works, even the LEDs!

Comment: Great find! This worked perfectly for my g502 under Antergos.

Comment: libratbag itself also has command line tools which are very straightforward to use and work perfectly well

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!
And the ability to turn of the fokkin LEDs is amazing.

Comment: This works so well, it feels like an official driver!

Comment: Do not work for me. At minimum speed ( on ubuntu and the mousse) the cursor is still too fast ... I need the same speed on all my device. /: It's important when you play FPS ...

Comment: Yeah, this no longer seems to work. The LED settings do not work at all. The DPI does but it's not very useful. You could just use the top two buttons to control the DPI easier than this software. Seems there isn't a good solution :(

Comment: Piper is limited in DPI options and the first led does not work.

Comment: 'sudo apt install piper' is sufficient for Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.  There is no need to add any additional PPA.

Comment: On Debian Bookworm, piper alone isn't sufficient; however, installing ratbagd "woke up" the DPI setting buttons, etc. on my system.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be too late but I am still answering anyway. As I know there is no software for linux. So what I do (and every body else) is that I use another computer that runs Windows to configure my mouse. The macros, lights are stored in the mouse so they can work anywhere(linux included).

What you can also do is used a virtual machine (running windows or mac) and do a usb pass through. I know the virtual machine can work (to configure the mouse) but never tested it.

Hope you find what I said useful. :)

Comment: The OP says: "I am NOT willing to setup a profile under a Windows environment". Your answer seems to ignore it. Still it may be useful to other users who are not as restrictive as the OP.

Comment: sorry I didn't read correctly. my bad.